# Configuring Amazon SES: Display Domain Different from Verified Domain

Tags: amazon-ses

I have set up an Amazon SES identity for my actual domain ***myrealdomain.com***. However, I want the "From" field in my emails to display as if it's coming from a Cloudfront alternate domain name like ***mydomain.com***. Is it possible to configure Amazon SES to use a display domain different from the verified domain?

I have tried to create a new identity using the Cloudfront alternate domain name, but I don't know if it works, because the status is pending the whole time.

However, I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, and I would like to confirm whether it aligns with best practices or if there's a recommended way to achieve this configuration.

Any insights or guidance on configuring Amazon SES with a different display domain would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**:

SES config:

[image]

CloudFront config:

[image]

Route53 records (it doesn't seem right, because mydomain.com is not a hosted zone but an alternate domain name that CloudFront created):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple verified identities to AWS SES and then when you send an email through the SDK, specify the `Source` as whatever email address you want to send the email from. The source must be one of your verified identities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do I add a new identity, which is a kind of an alias? Is it even possible? I just added a photo to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: @LongLuong It seems like you set it up correctly. You need to wait for the pending verification identity to be verified before you can use it. Did you publish the DNS records for AWS to verify? Once they are verified, you can use either of those domains to send emails.

Comment: > "You need to wait for the pending verification identity to be verified before you can use it."
That is the neat part. I am not sure if it is getting verified, since this is not a real domain but an alias, which points to the real domain.

Comment: @LongLuong What do you mean by a domain alias? You need to add the DNS records to every domain in your verified identities in order to be able to send emails from it. Have you added the DNS records for `mydomain.com`?

Comment: I have added another photo showing what my CloudFront looks like. If I create another DNS record (which is an alias) with the same name as 'www.mydomain.com,' will it mess up my CloudFront?

Comment: @LongLuong SES and Cloudfront are 2 completely separate things. If you want to be able to send email from `mydomain.com`, you will need to add the CNAME records that AWS gave you in your DNS settings (in AWS Route 53, Godaddy, etc.) in order to verify your domain as a verified email sender. All this has nothing to do with Cloudfront. The CNAME records SES gave you won't conflict with the CNAME record you set up for your Cloudfront Alternate Domain Name.

Comment: I created it (see the photo I added, though it doesn't look good). I understand the issue is that SES requires verification of a domain defined somewhere. Initially, I thought it might be related to CloudFront(the alternate domain name `mydomain.com`), but you mentioned that I am missing a record in Route53. Consequently, I created one. However, I can only add a new CNAME record based on my `realdomainname.com` and it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: If you don't own `mydomain.com`, that is if you didn't buy it from a domain registrar, you can't send email from it.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I can access `mydomain.com` the whole time because my teammate defined it somewhere else but AWS, which I didn't know. So technically, I own `mydomain.com`, and CloudFront was also able to use it as an alternate domain name. Thank you very much!